# Why pin image is not displayed?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, plist

I load annotations from a plist file and also I need to read images for a pin from the plist file.

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray *anns = [dict objectForKey:@"Category1"];
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[dict objectForKey:anns] valueForKey:@"Icon"]];
```

My plist construction:

[image: plist]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
NSArray *anns = [dict objectForKey:@"Category1"];
pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[dict objectForKey:anns] valueForKey:@"Icon"]];
                                                        ^^^^
```

`anns` is an array, so it can't be the key of your dictionary. My guess is that you want this:

```
NSArray *anns = [dict objectForKey:@"Category1"];
pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[anns objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Icon"]];
```

Comment: Yes, now working! But it show same image for Category1 and Category2, how it can be configured? Thanks!